# Inserting data into SQL Server by using a stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a problem while inserting records into SQL Server.

The string from C# doesn't show up in SQL Server as I'm inserting the sql just insert the first char

Example: If I insert 22222 in the data base just the first 2 inserted

Note I'm using a stored procedure for my first time.

This is my code:

```
public void insert_workshop(DateTime Pdate, string PTime, string PDesc, byte[] Img)
{
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("[InsertWorkShops]", conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@WorkshopsDate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = Pdate;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Time", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = PTime;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@WorkshopsDescription", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = PDesc;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@WorkshopsImage", SqlDbType.Image).Value = Img;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@CreatedBy", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = 1;

        try
        {
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Msg = "Add Done ";
        }
        catch
        {
            Msg = "Error While Adding";
        }

        WorkShopTransactions Ws = new WorkShopTransactions();
        Ws.insert_workshop(WorkShopDT.Value, txtWorshopTime.Text.ToString(),
                          txtWorkshopDescriptions.Text.ToString(), img);
```

T-SQL:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertWorkShops] 
    @WorkshopsDate date,
    @Time nvarchar, 
    @WorkshopsDescription nvarchar,
    @WorkshopsImage image,
    @CreatedBy int
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    insert into Workshops 
    values(@WorkshopsDate, @Time, @WorkshopsDescription, @WorkshopsImage, @CreatedBy)
END
```

Comment: Also `image` is deprecated and why isn't time given a `time` datatype?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the stored procedure, you have declared your `nvarchar` parameters without a length. They default to `nvarchar(1)`.

Comment: Thanks A lot every thing now is fine